# SQL function to manipulate values

Tags: sql-server, function

I am trying to write a T-SQL function to manipulate data as below. What is best way to do this?

- if number --> no change;
- if < 0.03 then 0.029;
- if > 0.03 then 0.031;
- if < -0.03 then -0.031;
- if 0.12 then 0.119;
- if < 1 then 0.99
- if non-number then null

Comment: Have a look at the `case` expression in SQL.

Comment: You can write an UDF

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far?  If we can see you code we can tell what is/isn't working?

Comment: What is the datatype of your input

Comment: My input datatype is float. Sorry, I could update my script in question and could not post in answer also.And comment does not allow due to length.

Answer (score 0):

I found it easier to work with IF CLAUSES when evaluating expressions. Just an answer, probably not the most polite for sure. Hope it helps

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ManipulateValues]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Parameter  float

AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @break_var as int
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    set @break_var = 0

    IF NOT(ISNUMERIC(@Parameter)=1)
    BEGIN
    SET @Parameter = NULL
    set @break_var = 1
    END

    IF @Parameter < 0.03 AND @break_var = 0
    BEGIN
    SET @Parameter = 0.029
    set @break_var = 1
    END

    IF @Parameter > 0.03 AND @break_var = 0
    BEGIN
    SET @Parameter = 0.031
    set @break_var = 1
    END

    IF @Parameter < -0.03 AND @break_var = 0
    BEGIN
    SET @Parameter = -0.031
    set @break_var = 1
    END

    IF @Parameter = 0.12 AND @break_var = 0
    BEGIN
    SET @Parameter = 0.119
    set @break_var = 1
    END

    IF @Parameter < 1 AND @break_var = 0
    BEGIN
    SET @Parameter = 0.99
    set @break_var = 1
    END


    SELECT @Parameter

END
```

Comment: The float or number used are just the example.There suppose to be variables instead of them eg<0.03 to 0.029 means '<0.03' to '0.029' or '<x' to 'x-0.01' if x is less than 1 and so on.