# SQL function to map key to value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a SQL function to map keys to values. The goal is to migrate a table that contains Windows timezone names to iana timezone name, something like this

```
Insert Into IanaTable (IanaTimezone)
Select TzConvert(WindowsTimeZone)
From WindowsTzTable
```

I see that there is around 50 windows timezones and willing to write manual conversion for those 50 items. I have looked at some other answers but I hope not to write a very big IF/ELSE function

[SQL function to manipulate values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34415063/sql-function-to-manipulate-values)

Comment: So what is your question? What are you stuck on?

Comment: I would like to write a function without having to 
If A Return A1
If B return B1
...
50 times

Comment: How else can you map them? I assume you've considered storing the mapping in a table?

Comment: That is what I am wondering. If SQL Server had something like Javascript or C# where we can just define the map/data temporarily, outside of the control logic, It would be absolutely clean to do
{ "key1" : "value1" , "key2" : "value2","key3" : "value3"} 
And the function can just return myMap[inputKey]
It will separate the logic from the data. I do not know if it have something like that

Comment: It absolutely does, it's called a table :) this is a relational database after all :). Create a table with a column for the key and a column for the value, and then query it when you need to map a value.

Comment: This will also perform *much* better than a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IF` is used for flow control. For expressions, just use `CASE`:

```
Insert Into IanaTable (IanaTimezone)
    Select 
        case
            when CONDITION1 then RESULT1
            when CONDITION2 then RESULT2
            ......
            when CONDITION100 the RESULT100
        end as IanaTimezone         
    From WindowsTzTable
```

Edit: Since OP stated that they would prefer a function because the same value will be assigned to multiple columns, I counterpropose a lateral join to alias the expression. This is better since even copy-pasting the name of a function is still WET and prone to errors. Here:

```
Insert Into IanaTable (...)
    Select 
         q1.IanaTimezone as column1
        ,q1.IanaTimezone as column2
        ,q1.IanaTimezone as column3
        ,othervalue      as othercolumn
        ......
    From 
        WindowsTzTable
        cross apply
        (
            Select 
            case
                when CONDITION1 then RESULT1
                when CONDITION2 then RESULT2
                ......
                when CONDITION100 the RESULT100
            end as IanaTimezone 
        ) as q1
```

Comment: Thanks @George ! Can you help me to re-write it into a function?
I would like to simplify it a bit since I actually have a big insert that pull data from other tables already

Comment: Functions generally have less performance. Do you mean that there are multiple sources so you don't want to write the same formula twice?

Comment: I meant that the INSERT INTO clause is trying to insert quite a few more columns ( around 10 ) that's why a thought it would be better to move that transformation / mapping to a function so it looks a little bit cleaner

Comment: The same value to multiple columns? You can use a `cross apply` to alias. I'll illustrate this in the answer.